# Magento 2 get special price product collection

Tags: magento2, collection, special-price

I want to get all sale products (**which have specila price and special from date and special to date**) in a .phtml file. Which i use in any where in store.specially in list page.

Comment: you want to `is_saleable` product?

Comment: which i apply special price special date to 2 form, those products i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create your own block file and get collection below way..

```
<?php

    namespace Vendor\SaleProducts\Block\Home;

    use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;

    class SaleList extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct {

        protected $_collection;

        protected $categoryRepository;

        protected $_resource;

        public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, 
                \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper, 
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver, 
                CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
                \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper, 
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection, 
                \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
                array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
            $this->_collection = $collection;
            $this->_resource = $resource;

            parent::__construct($context, $postDataHelper, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository, $urlHelper, $data);
        }

        public function getProducts() {
            $count = $this->getProductCount();
            $category_id = $this->getData("category_id");
            $collection = clone $this->_collection;
            $collection->clear()->getSelect()->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::WHERE)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::ORDER)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_COUNT)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::LIMIT_OFFSET)->reset(\Magento\Framework\DB\Select::GROUP);

            if(!$category_id) {
                $category_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
            }
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($category_id);
            $now = date('Y-m-d');
            if(isset($category) && $category) {
                $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                    ->addFinalPrice()
                    ->addTaxPercents()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_from_date')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_to_date')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', ['neq' => ''])
                    ->addAttributeToFilter([
                        [
                            'attribute' => 'special_from_date',
                            'lteq' => date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($now)),
                            'date' => true,
                        ],
                        [
                            'attribute' => 'special_to_date',
                            'gteq' => date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($now)),
                            'date' => true,
                        ]
                    ])
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left');
            } else {
                $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                    ->addFinalPrice()
                    ->addTaxPercents()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', ['neq' => ''])
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_from_date')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('special_to_date')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter([
                        [
                            'attribute' => 'special_from_date',
                            'lteq' => date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($now)),
                            'date' => true,
                        ],
                        [
                            'attribute' => 'special_to_date',
                            'gteq' => date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($now)),
                            'date' => true,
                        ]
                    ])
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left');
            }

            $collection->getSelect()
                    ->limit($count);

            return $collection;
        }

        public function getLoadedProductCollection() {
            return $this->getProducts();
        }

        public function getProductCount() {
            $limit = $this->getData("product_count");
            if(!$limit)
                $limit = 10;
            return $limit;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use in the template this:

```
<?php foreach ($block->getLoadedProductCollection() as $product) : ?>
    <!-- do something with $product -->
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Sir ?  $logger->debug('query is '. $collection->getSelect()->__toString());
it return a query in debug.log file. and i past this query into mysql it return 0 row.

Comment: First i get this collection in .phtml file and no effect. then i debug the query it return 0 row Sir. 
I want to get all the discounted products can you please Help me Sir ?

Comment: you can see in this screenshot  https://screenshots.firefox.com/4oL1HpUJtrED4cqH/dev.marketplace.com

Comment: i get the discounted product collection and set on page. 

But here 1 issue . this collection return just all those product in which we add `Advance Price` when `add new Product` .

But when we set discount via `marketing promotion` -> `Catalog Price rule` then above code don't return those all product of this `rule` 

how can get also `Catalog Price Rule` collection as well `advance price` product get.

Comment: above code is mate special price collection

Comment: Sir How can also get `Catalog Price Rule` products also ? 

in db i found `catalogrule_product` table in which all marketing promotion product id exist

Comment: i have currently outsite of my office but this link is may be help you!! :Ref
https://webkul.com/blog/product-collection-satisfies-catalog-rule-magento2/

Comment: oh its okay Sor take easy thank you

Comment: but i want to get also catalog price rule products also?